# Compare a column in 2 excel files in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 excel sheets with almost same information.

1st sheet looks like :

```
ID Name empnumber
1  abc  123
2  xyz  234
```

2nd sheet looks like :

```
ID Name empnumber
1  abc  234
2  xyz  345
```

My 1st sheet contains **temporary** Employee number and 2nd sheet contains **final** employee number.

I am trying to create a macro which will update my first sheet-empnumber column
 depending upon my second sheet by compairing Name or ID value.

I will take 1st and 2nd excel files as user input. also comparing column (Name/Id) in inputbox so user will decide what to match.

Pseudo-code:

```
if abc from 1st sheet==abc from 2nd sheet
then 
 emp number of abc in 1st sheet = empnumber of abc from 2nd sheet.
```

How do I do this in VBA?

Here goes my code:

```
Dim FileNameA As String
Dim FileNameB As String
Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

strRangeToCheck = "A1:B5"

iRet = MsgBox("Select forecast file", vbYes, "Forecast file")
FileNameA = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If FileNameA = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileNameA)
Set sh1 = wbkA.Sheets("Sheet1")
varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)

iRet = MsgBox("Select Actual file", vbYes, "Actual file")
FileNameB = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If FileNameB = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileNameB)
Set sh2 = wbkB.Sheets("Sheet1")
varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)

strcompareColumn = InputBox("Please enter column name to compare", "Data Entry")
strUpdateColumn = InputBox("Please enter column name to update", "Data Entry")
```

End Sub

Now I need to find exact row/column from 1st sheet, take value from second sheet and update 1st sheet.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett : Edited my question and added code. Please help..

Comment: You could easily solve it using `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: @t.thielemans : I don't want to use formula. I need to use macro , as there are many other things also I need to include in code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option without using a macro, only works if your files are static. You have your 2 files and you open them in the same Excel instance (easiest way to reference them). In your main file you add this formula to one of your cells.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$C$4;3;0));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;[Book2]Sheet1!$B$2:$C$4;2;0));"";VLOOKUP(B2;[Book2]Sheet1!$B$2:$C$4;2;0));VLOOKUP(A2;[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$C$4;3;0))
```

Comment: I thought about using a formula while reading the question but couldn't come up with one so +1 for doing it!